# Почему при разбивке строки на массивы подстрок, программа выдаёт неоднозначный (для меня) результат?

Tags: java

**Дано:**

```
String str = "1 + 2 = ";
```

**Цель: разбить строку на два массива:**

1. - с числами;
2. - с математическими операторами;

**Моё решение:**

```
String[] nums = str.split("[\\s-+/*=]+");
String[] mathSymbols = str.split("[\\s\\d]+");
```

**Ожидаемый результат при выводе массивов:**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));         // [1, 2] - всё верно
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mathSymbols));  // [, +, =] - не верно (в моём понимании), 
                                                                 предполагалось: [+, =]
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему такой вывод второго массива?
2. Как правильно разбить строку в данном случае?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод split() разбивает строку на массив по значение между найденными подстроками. У тебя regexp ищет группы пробелов и букв. Получается разделения происходит между "1 " и " 2 ", перед "1 " у тебя ничего нет, там происходит разделение, вот тебе и возвращается сначала пустая строка, а затем уже операторы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. если при разбивке строки по конкретному элементу (группе элементов) с целью исключения таких элементов из строки (образно говоря) в случае, когда исключаемый элемент стоит первым, то первым элементом, возвращаемого массива, будет пустая строка? Можно ли её убрать сразу при первоначальной разбивке?

Comment: через split нет, можно раз regex используешь, распарсить строку через него, дав имена группам
`(?<nums>[\s-+\/*=]+)|(?<mathSymbols>[\s\d]+)` 
Забей regexp на https://regex101.com/ и справа увидишь результат
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm

Answer (score 0):

Мой костыль:

```
String s = "1 + 2 = ";
String[] nums = outputStream.toString().split("[\\s-+*=]+");
String[] mathSymbols = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")+1).matches("[\\d\\s]+") ?
            s.replace(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")+1), "").split("[\\s\\d]+") :
            s.split("[\\s\\d]+");
```